# Exception after join package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging to the template web-api project

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core-mvc

After join to the template project of the web application package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging older than version 6.0.0-preview6. * Or new 6.0.0-rc. *, It ends with an exception

```
MissingMethodException: 
Method not found: 'System.Action`4 <Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger, !! 0, !! 1, 
    System.Exception> Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerMessage.Define (
        Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel , 
        Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventId, 
        System.String, 
        Boolean
    ) '.
```

crashes somewhere inside IEndpointRouteBuilder.MapControllers call

Has anyone encountered such a problem before? How to solve it (of course, except for downgrading to the old version)?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes in Visual Studio, it will ignore the preview version, you can try to check it.

Go Tools -> Options, then select Preview Features as per the screenshot below. Make sure to tick the “Use previews of the .NET Core SDK”.

Without this, Visual Studio will use the latest version of the .NET SDK installed, that is *not* a preview version.

[image]

If the above method does not work, can you show your csproj file?